# GUI App from REPO to deleting config files of removed packages

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, cleanup

Im looking for a gtk gui application from official repository to deleting config files of removed packages. BleachBit dont offer this. Ubuntu-Cleaner is perfect but isnt in official repositories. I know is a free software and ppa with him installing only appliaction, no additional dependencies but im always nervous when i have installed something outside official repo in my os. Is something similiar to ubuntu-cleaner avaiable in official repository ?

Answer (score 0):

[Stacer](https://oguzhaninan.github.io/Stacer-Web/) has been recently (as in a few years ago) added to the official repositories. This is a multi-purpose tool but one of its features is identical to the software you mentioned.

No 3rd party repositories (PPA) needed. Just install as usual from the ofical repository:

```
sudo apt install stacer
```

Comment: Cant see option for searching and deleting config files of removed packages without "purge" option or im blind. This option interests me.